# scraping two columns from the given url in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to scrape the data from the [Trending tickers - Yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers) and I have to get only the symbols and the names of the companies from the table, I've written the code for the entire table but how can I get the required columns?

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas


url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"yfinlist-table W(100%) BdB Bdc($tableBorderGray)"})

tableRows = [[td.text for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]]
tableHeaders = [th.text for th in table.find_all("th")]
df = pandas.DataFrame(tableRows,columns = tableHeaders)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly scraped all the rows. But, to get only the symbol and the name, you'll have to loop over the rows one by one and get them in each iteration. If you right click and inspect any symbol, you can see that the text is located inside an `<a>` tag. The corresponding `<a>` tags have the following format:

```
<a href="/quote/S?p=S" title="Sprint Corporation" data-symbol="S" class="Fw(b)" data-reactid="57">S</a>
```

As you can see, the name is included in the tag with the `title` attribute. So, to get both, the symbol, and the name, you only have to get the tag. As it is the *first* `<a>` tag inside a row, you can simply get it using `row.find('a')`.

Complete code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', class_='yfinlist-table W(100%) BdB Bdc($tableBorderGray)')
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    a_tag = row.find('a')
    symbol = a_tag.text
    name = a_tag['title']
    print(symbol, name)
```

Output:

```
S Sprint Corporation
TMUS T-Mobile US, Inc.
AAPL Apple Inc.
^HSI HANG SENG INDEX
^N225 Nikkei 225
000001.SS SSE Composite Index
WMT Walmart Inc.
NKE NIKE, Inc.
^FTSE FTSE 100
^AORD ALL ORDINARIES
BTC-USD Bitcoin USD
CL=F Crude Oil
MCD McDonald's Corporation
AUDUSD=X AUD/USD
KO The Coca-Cola Company
DIS The Walt Disney Company
GBPUSD=X GBP/USD
GERN Geron Corporation
^NSEI NIFTY 50
TSLA Tesla, Inc.
VZ Verizon Communications Inc.
EURUSD=X EUR/USD
^BSESN S&P BSE SENSEX
GC=F Gold
0700.HK Tencent Holdings Limited
^KS11 KOSPI Composite Index
```

Comment: I'm getting an error here `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')`. What does `lxml` mean? The error says like this `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?` @Keyur Potdar

Comment: Use `html.parser` then. You have to install `lxml` parser. Use `pip install lxml`. You can use any one of them; the solution works for both.

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) to know more about different parsers.

Comment: It's a nice piece of code. However, only this portion will suffice `soup.find('table', class_='yfinlist-table')` to get the data.

Comment: @SIM, yes, that will suffice. I just copied the full class name from the question.

Comment: If I want to write the printed data into a file what should I do? @KeyurPotdar

Comment: [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module might help you for that.